# PowerDesigner: How to get reason for "No data can be generated for the table xyz"

Tags: sqlanywhere, powerdesigner

I've reverse engineered a database via PowerDesigner. Now I want to create test data for this database (lot of tables, lot of references...) but failing during process with message:

```
No data can be generated for the table xyz
```

Unfortunately xyz are most of my tables of the database and I'm seeking for a reason, why it's not able to do so.

The tables are using a PK of type uniqueidentifier set via newid(). Also it's highly nested in stricture. So one entry on top might need 30 or 40 entries in other tables in sum -- but the Impact and Lineage Analysis is finding them so I can browser them from there.

When checking model I've got a number of warnings about missing indexes etc. But no error message.

Comment: Do the failing tables have something in common? Type of PK, selected test data profile... Did you define some specific constraints on the generated data? like 100% of unique values on a 5-values list to generate 20 rows... Or are you mostly using the default?

Comment: Defaults for the start.